# Angular material not behaving correctly

Tags: angular

[Gif of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhuYj.gif)
[Material Rendering Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciO4V.png)

Ive got an expansion panel , but it is in a constant open state.
Ive imported the needed css files in Angular.json and other components work.

Im using the example from https://v14.material.angular.io/components/expansion/examples

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        This is the expansion title
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        This is a summary of the content
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>This is the primary content of the panel.</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel >
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        Self aware panel
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        Currently I am 
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>I'm visible because I am open</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Angular.json

```
 "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
```

Angular version 14

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Expected behavior:
Mat panel should hide its contents until clicked.

Tried:
Removing Bootstrap css files  and js files.
Added Browser module BrowserAnimationsModule to Imports
Using different version of the angular material documentation.
adding

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

to styles.css

edit: found console errors with animation module not loading

```
core.mjs:6387 ERROR Error: NG03402: Unable to process animations due to the following failed trigger transitions
 NG03505: @expansionHeight has failed due to:
 NG03003: Please provide a value for the animation param collapsedHeight
NG03505: @expansionHeight has failed due to:
 NG03003: Please provide a value for the animation param collapsedHeight
    at triggerTransitionsFailed (browser.mjs:132:12)
    at TransitionAnimationEngine.reportError (browser.mjs:3509:15)
    at TransitionAnimationEngine._flushAnimations (browser.mjs:3674:18)
    at TransitionAnimationEngine.flush (browser.mjs:3473:32)
    at InjectableAnimationEngine.flush (browser.mjs:4320:32)
    at animations.mjs:213:29
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:372:26)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:134:43)
    at NgZone.runOutsideAngular (core.mjs:26393:28)
    at AnimationRendererFactory.end (animations.mjs:211:24)
```

Answer (score 0):

Strangely my package.json file had @angular/material at

```
    "@angular/material": "^7.0.0",
```

I updated this to

```
    "@angular/material": "14.2.7",
```

and ran npm install

versions located at
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/material?activeTab=versions

this fixed my issue